# How to check if a button is checkbox on 64 bit windows?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm checking if a button is checkbox of 32bit process on 64bit windows10.

The problem is that I can not distingush checkbox from normal button.

## The buttons are different in [Window-Detective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/):

[image]

(**After I restart the application, even Window-Detective shows it is a button now!**)

## But the checkbox can't be recognized as checkbox in Spy++

[image]

`BS_CHECKBOX` is not listed.

## Code (compiled as 32bit):

```
TEST_METHOD(ShouldCheckStyle) {
    auto styleOfButton =    ::GetWindowLongPtr((HWND)0x003F06E8, GWL_STYLE);
    auto styleOfCheckbox =  ::GetWindowLongPtr((HWND)0x01101642, GWL_STYLE);
    auto bsOfButton =       styleOfButton & BS_TYPEMASK;
    auto bsOfCheckbox =     styleOfCheckbox & BS_TYPEMASK;
    auto resultOfButton =   (bsOfButton == BS_CHECKBOX);
    auto resultOfCheckbox = (bsOfCheckbox == BS_CHECKBOX);
    auto debugger = 0;
}
```

## Debug output

[image]

The code indicates they both have `BS_OWNERDRAW`. The above behaves the same for the button and the checkbox.

The weird thing is Window-Detective can recognize the style of checkbox. The code is same as I used above. Here's a piece of code:

```
Window* WindowManager::createWindow(HWND handle) {
    WindowClass* windowClass = getWindowClassFor(handle);

    String className = windowClass->getName().toLower();
    if (className == "button") {
        LONG typeStyle = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE) & BS_TYPEMASK;
        switch (typeStyle) {
          case BS_CHECKBOX:
          case BS_AUTOCHECKBOX:
          case BS_3STATE:
          case BS_AUTO3STATE: {
              return new CheckBox(handle, windowClass);
          }
          case BS_RADIOBUTTON:
          case BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON: {
              return new RadioButton(handle, windowClass);
          }
          case BS_GROUPBOX: {
              return new GroupBox(handle, windowClass);
          }
          default: {
              // If none of the above is true, then the control is just a Button
              return new Button(handle, windowClass);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: On the face of it I'd say Window Detective is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I can see the `0x01101642` is a checkbox in dialog.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I think both SPY++ and my code have the same problem, they only extract `BS_OWNERDRAW`, that looks wrong since a button or a checkbox should have other Button-Styles.

Comment: Maybe you can try UI Automation to check what it sees. No need to code, just run inspect.exe SDK tool.

Comment: If your button has the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style (which has the value 0x0B) then that will hide any `BS_CHECKBOX` (0x02) or `BS_AUTOCHECKBOX` (0x03) style bits.

Comment: @SimonMourier UI Automation shows it's button. After I restart the application, even Window-Detective shows it is a button now.

Comment: The button type styles are basically an enumeration. You can't have `BS_CHECKBOX` and `BS_OWNERDRAW` set at the same time; it's meaningless. If the bottom 8 bits equal 0xb then the button's type is `BS_OWNERDRAW`.

Comment: @AdrianMole @JonathanPotter so is there any way to check if a `BS_OWNERDRAW` button is actual a checkbox?

Comment: Not unless you put some other signal in yourself.

Comment: A `BS_OWNERDRAW` button isn't a checkbox. If it **looks** like a checkbox it's because that's how it's being owner-drawn.

Comment: Maybe you can think from another angle. If only the checkbox has the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style, then you can check all the buttons. If there is `BS_OWNERDRAW` in the style, it is the checkbox, provided that other buttons are not owner-drawn with `BS_OWNERDRAW`.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT No, both have `BS_OWNERDRAW` style, the checkbox can respond BM_GETCHECK/BM_SETCHECK. I'm finding a way to distinguish them by checking their properties.

Comment: It's very strange, these all buttons are created by yourself, if you need to distinguish them, you just to give them a unique control identifier or control title. Such as: `(HMENU)IDB_CHECKBOX`

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT They are in another process, not created by me

Comment: All right, It looks like you can't modify the source code. From [BS_OWNERDRAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles), do not combine the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style with any other button styles.  Therefore, when set `BS_OWNERDRAW`, `BS_CHECKBOX` will not work.

Comment: By the way, you run the process, can you see these buttons include checkbox  from the main window?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT  I can see both checkbox and buttons in a pop-up dialog. Checkbox is for "Agree term", buttons for "Confirm" or "Cancel".

Comment: You can simply judge the owner-drawn checkbox from the pop-up dialog, then, I believe your problem should have be solved.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT How to 'judge the owner-drawn checkbox from the pop-up dialog'? It is not owned by me. you mean dll-injection? It will be too complex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209555/discussion-between-strive-sun-msft-and-user1633272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion, you can use [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) to get the text from each control and compare the specific text.

`BS_CHECKBOX` cannot be detected from the properties of the "checkbox" control beacuse of [BS_OWNERDRAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles).

> Creates an owner-drawn button. The owner window receives a WM_DRAWITEM
>   message when a visual aspect of the button has changed. Do not combine
>   the BS_OWNERDRAW style with any other button styles.

Try the below code:

```
WCHAR str1[20];
WCHAR str2[] = L"Agree me";

GetWindowText(hwnd_checkbox, str1, 256);
if (_tcscmp(str1, str2) == 0)
{
    //it is checkbox                        
}
else
{
    //it isn't checkbox
}
```

After you get the correct control handle of the checkbox, you can use [SendDlgItemMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-senddlgitemmessagea) or `SendMessage` to send `BM_SETCHECK` check message.

`SendMessage(hwnd_checkbox, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 0);`